# Unable to import nor install Pyhook (64 or 32) in Python 3.6

Tags: python

This is the line of feedback I am getting. I have tried to follow other people who have asked these questions but the answers usually provided to them are not being beneficial to me. I am running my Python instance inside Spyder. Any assistance or tips would be appreciated.

```
import pyhook, pythoncom, sys, logging
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-413e5591e9f3>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyhook, pythoncom, sys, logging

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyhook'

pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
  File "<ipython-input-4-00dcce36920f>", line 1
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl
  File "<ipython-input-5-1c4f31ceb6a2>", line 1
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to run `pip` inside of Python?

`pip` is designed as a command line tool and should be run in a command line terminal.

You can, however, run it from inside python by running:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'pyHook'])
```